# Set value of property with private accessor

Tags: c#, .net

I have this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

If I write this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Name = "Nocigar";
```

I get a compiler error, obviously. But if I write this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    Action<Foo, string> act = Build();
    act(foo, "Woot");

    Debug.WriteLine(foo.Name);
}

static Action<Foo, string> Build()
{
    ParameterExpression fooParam =
        Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo),
        "foo");

    ParameterExpression nameParam =
        Expression.Parameter(typeof(string),
        "name");

    MemberExpression propertyValue =
        Expression.Property(fooParam,
        "Name");

    BinaryExpression assignExpression =
        Expression.Assign(propertyValue,
        nameParam);

    LambdaExpression lambda =
        Expression.Lambda(typeof(Action<Foo, string>),
        assignExpression,
        fooParam,
        nameParam);

    return (Action<Foo, string>)lambda.Compile();
}
```

It compiles and runs without a problem, writing "Woot" to the debug window. What gives?

I am intending to make use of this feature in some code to map from a data reader to a POCO. I am concerned that it may be a side effect rather than intended behaviour and wonder if anyone can shed light on the reasons for it.

Comment: With expressions you're emitting code like you _may_ do with `Reflection.Emit` but member accessibility is restricted only by compiler at compile-time (it's enforced by run-time only for method **signature**) then with Expressions you'll bypass that check (as you may do using raw Reflection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a side effect.With reflection or expressions you can access private members like this for example:

```
var dateTimeType = typeof (DateTime);
MethodInfo[] privateMthods = dateTimeType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
privateMthods.ToList().ForEach(a=> Console.WriteLine(a.Name.ToString()));
```

As written in the book "metaprogramming in .NET" by  Kevin Hazzard and Jason Bock

"There’s also a NonPublic value, which means that you can see
private and protected content via the Reflection API. Depending on your view, this
may seem like a severe security breach when you consider that this allows arbitrary
code to change the values of private fields in an object. But only privileged code can
use the reflection calls. If you don’t have this level of access, your use of reflection will
fail." -page 46

You may also consider this(again from the above mentioned book):

"As you’ve probably already guessed with a Windows 8 application and its security
model, you can only access public members; you can’t access private members. Again,
these changes are strictly for Windows 8 applications. If you’re targeting .NET 4.5 outside
of Windows 8, you can still use the full Type class." -- page 318

This article is also helpful:
[Security Considerations for Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc.aspx)